# DoExpressCheckoutPayment 呼び出し時のエラーについて

Tags: paypal

PayPalのエクスプレスチェックアウトの処理時に以下2つのエラーが返ってきました。

```
L_ERRORCODE0: 10422
L_SHORTMESSAGE0: Customer must choose new funding sources.
L_LONGMESSAGE0: The customer must return to PayPal to select new funding sources.
L_SEVERITYCODE0: 空
```

```
L_ERRORCODE0: 10486
L_SHORTMESSAGE0: This transaction couldn't be completed.
L_LONGMESSAGE0: This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer to PayPal.
L_SEVERITYCODE0: 空
```

これはどんなエラーかわかるかたいますか？エラー原因に合わせて注文者にメッセージを出そうかと思っているのでよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

【 L_ERRORCODE0: 10422】
支払い方法(資金源)に問題があり決済できないというエラーだと思います。別の支払い方法の案内をしてはどうでしょうか。また、再度決済してもらうには、もう一度SetECから実行してもらう必要があるはずです。ただ根本の原因はわからないので、そこはカード会社に聞くしかないでしょうね。

【 L_ERRORCODE0: 10486】
同じく資金源に問題があり決済できていないと思われます。こっちはクレジットカードの限度額やオーソリエラーのように見えます。この10486エラーの場合は処理を再試行することでエラーを回復させることができます。

DoExpressCheckoutPayment APIで"L_ERRORCODE0"に10486というエラーコードが返却された場合に、再度PayPal決済画面 (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXXX) にリダイレクトしてもらう処理で、詳細は以下のURLを参照してみてください。

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/